# FileCopy with a date and wildcard

Tags: vbscript

The file is called: "Data_20170123_(random number).csv" .  The date changes each day and the number is random.  I am trying to create a batch file, that will perform a file copy to another directory and rename it by taking out the date and random number.  The asterik isn't working on line 9.

Can I use a `Left` string or `InStr` to do the `CopyFile`?

I appreciate your help in advance.  My code looks like this.

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim fso, ts
Dim WshShell

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
ts = timeStamp

fso.CopyFile "C:\Temp\Data_" & ts & "_*.csv", "C:\Logs\Data.csv", True

'======
Function timeStamp() 
    timeStamp = Year(Now) & _
                Right("0" & Month(Now), 2)  & _
                Right("0" & Day(Now), 2)
End Function
'====== 
'this does work but it's using the random number so I need a wildcard?
'fso.CopyFile "C:\Temp\Data_" & ts & "_11.csv", "C:\Logs\Data.csv", True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim fso, ts, folder, file
Dim WshShell

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
ts = timeStamp
Set folder = ofso.GetFolder("C:\temp")
For Each file in folder.Files
    If Left(file.name, 14) = "Data_" & ts & "_" And Right(file.Name, 4) = ".csv" Then
        fso.CopyFile file.Path, "C:\Logs\Data.csv",True
    End If
Next

Function timeStamp() 
    timeStamp = Year(Now) & _
    Right("0" & Month(Now),2)  & _
    Right("0" & Day(Now),2)
End Function
```

The above code checks every file in the given folder and matches the known parts of the filename.  Any file that matches is copied to the target folder with the specific name.  You could use an `Exit For` once the copy is complete to speed up the code as well - since you only ever copy to a single filename I'm presuming there's only ever a single file to copy, so exiting the loop once you find the right file is fine.

You're not using your WshShell object at all so it's not needed either, but I've left it alone in case it's part of the code you haven't shown.